# How do you find the distribution with three random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am working on a problem from probability theory and seem to be getting stuck. The problem is the following:

P is a distribution {1, 0, 1} all with probability 1/3

Let (X, Y, Z) ~ p as random variables.

My question: How do you set up the distribution for this? Is this just

P(X = -1) = 1/3
P(X = 0) = 1/3
P(X = 1) = 1/3

or is it

P(X = -1) = 1/3
P(Y = 0) = 1/3
P(Z = 1) = 1/3

The next question is to find E(X + Y + Z) so I imagine it is the latter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more like your first one. For the random variable $X$ alone, it holds that
$$X = \begin{cases} -1, & \text{w/ probability }1/3 \\ 0, & \text{w/ probability } 1/3 \\ 1, & \text{w/ probability } 1/3\end{cases}$$
and the same is true for $Y$ and also for $Z$.

Here's a useful way to think of it: imagine that $X$ is the result of rolling a [3-sided die](https://www.mathartfun.com/d357.html), but its three sides were $-1$, $0$, and $1$. Suppose now that you have three of such dice (let's say a white one, a black one, and a green one); in this way, $X$ is the result of rolling the white one, $Y$ the result of rolling the black one, and $Z$ the result of rolling the green one.

Your question is a bit unclear, so I'm not sure if you're asked for the joint distribution of $X, Y,$ and $Z$, or if you're asked about the distribution of $X + Y + Z$. In either case, your task is essentially the same; you must explore all $3^3 = 27$ combinations of what the three dice can be. If you're asked about the distribution of $X + Y + Z$, note that it can be any value between $-3$ and $3$ inclusively, but not with equal probability; it's much more likely to be $0$ than $3$, for instance.

If you have the distribution of $X + Y + Z$, you can use it directly to compute $\mathbb E[X + Y + Z]$, or you can use the linearity of expectation and instead compute the equivalent expression $\mathbb E[X] + \mathbb E[Y] + \mathbb E[Z]$.

Comment: So just to clarify, the expected values for each of these (X, Y, Z) will all be the same right? With this distribution, I am getting that each E(X) etc is equal to 0. Does this intuitively seem right?

Comment: Correct, because each one has the same distribution as the others.

Comment: So the E(XYZ) would just equal 0 as well

Comment: Correct.${}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much! This is much clearer now!